# E_FAIL or S_FALSE, which is more appropriate to represent no such attribute?

Tags: c++, api, winapi, interface

I have a image detection module which is encapsulated as a COM module. I've exported a `Key/Value Getter` API like: `GetImageAttr(UINT key, void* pValue);`. Our product MAY or MAY NOT attach a special structure on image, so my client can query the specific structure through this API.

Possible usage is like:

```
ImageSpecialAttribute attr = {};
HRESULT hr = pImageDetector->GetImageAttr(IMAGE_SPECIAL_ATTRIBUTE, (void*)&attr);
```

It is trivial to return `S_OK` if the image does have such attached structure. But if it doesn't, should I return E_FAIL or S_FALSE?

1. S_FALSE: Everything is fine, just the image does not have such optional attribute.

   - Force user to check hr == S_OK
   - Querying a image without such optional attribute is not a error.
2. E_FAIL: No! Something is wrong. You should not query this key.

   - Client can easily check by FAILED(hr)
   - Using this key to query this non-existed value is a error.

Updated, (Thanks to Remy Lebeau)

3. HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND): No! No such element/attribute existed.

   - Client can easily check by FAILED(hr)
   - Although it represents a error, users still can know what's the meaning by checking `hr`.

Comment: IMO, anything returning `HRESULT` should be able to be tested using `FAILED()`, so you have my vote for option 2.

Comment: Some languages (e.g. Visual Basic) will translate `E_` codes into a runtime exception.  So, my advice would be to use similar rules as to how you would decide whether your C++ function throws on failure, or returns a status code.  Typically , functions should throw only in exceptional circumstances and if it *should* abort or disrupt the flow of execution of the code.

Comment: Regardless of which way you decide to go, make sure that you fill in the `attr` with neutral values if the attribute is not there.

Comment: Avoid using structures, they are difficult to marshal correctly (google IRecordInfo).   Use an interface instead.  An IsValid property on that interface would certainly be wise.  Avoid S_FALSE, there are not many language runtimes that allow client code to see that value.  And not many client programmers that think that they should catch an exception or that E_FAIL means anything.

Comment: @HansPassant: OLE uses `S_FALSE` everywhere, there is no reason to avoid it.  It can't be the only indication that the attribute is not present, but it's perfectly reasonable to use it in addition to another approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`S_FALSE` is a success value, not an error value.  Many of Microsoft's own COM APIs return `S_FALSE` when the method itself succeeds but the requested data is not available, or the requested operation is not performed. This is mentioned in Microsoft's documentation:

[Error Handling in COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485842.aspx)

> All of the constants with the prefix "E_" are error codes. The constants S_OK and S_FALSE are both success codes. Probably 99% of COM methods return S_OK when they succeed; but do not let this fact mislead you. A method might return other success codes, so always test for errors by using the [SUCCEEDED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687197.aspx) or [FAILED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474.aspx) macro.
>   ...
>   The success code S_FALSE deserves mention. Some methods use S_FALSE to mean, roughly, a negative condition that is not a failure. It can also indicate a "no-op"—the method succeeded, but had no effect. For example, the [CoInitializeEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx) function returns S_FALSE if you call it a second time from the same thread. If you need to differentiate between S_OK and S_FALSE in your code, you should test the value directly, but still use [FAILED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474.aspx) or [SUCCEEDED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687197.aspx) to handle the remaining cases...

I suggest you follow the same convention, eg:

```
HRESULT hr = pImageDetector->GetImageAttr(IMAGE_SPECIAL_ATTRIBUTE, (void*)&attr);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    if (hr != S_FALSE)
    {
        // use attribute as needed...
    }
    else
    {
        // attribute not found...
    }
}
else
{
    // error...
}
```

If you really want to return an error code for a non-existing attribute, I suggest you define a custom `HRESULT` for that specific condition, eg:

```
#define E_ATTR_NOT_FOUND MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_ERROR, FACILITY_ITF, 1)
```

Or:

```
#define E_ATTR_NOT_FOUND HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
```

And then you can return that error to the caller, eg:

```
HRESULT hr = pImageDetector->GetImageAttr(IMAGE_SPECIAL_ATTRIBUTE, (void*)&attr);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // use attribute as needed...
}
else if (hr == E_ATTR_NOT_FOUND)
{
    // attribute not found...
}
else
{
    // error...
}
```

COM does not define a standardized error HRESULT code for a "not found" condition (`HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND)` would be the closest standard equivilent).

Comment: HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND) looks like a great meaningful return code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following [the pattern of COM enumerators' `Next` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221369(v=vs.85).aspx)
where the number of objects retrieved is returned in an output parameter.  (`S_FALSE` is also returned if the object count is zero but the call was otherwise valid)

Because it is an output parameter, the client can't ignore it, and layers such as VB that hide HRESULTs from the user don't result in losing the information.

Comment: In fact, my thought about using S_FALSE most come from this COM's enumerator next method. It makes me think it may be reasonable to return S_FALSE if no such or more elements existed.
But, I sometimes misuse it and see many others misuse it too as testing it by FAILED(hr). This is why I post this question to wanna hear more opinions about this.

Comment: `S_FALSE` is perfectly fine to use as a "not found" return value.  It means the method succeeded but no action was taken. As such, it is a success value handled by `SUCCEEDED()`, not an error value handled by `FAILED()`. As for COM enumerators, `Next()` returns `S_FALSE` when the number of returned objects is less than the number of requested objects. That includes the condition that the number is 0, but it does not mean 0 specifically. For example, if you request 5 objects and `Next()` returns 2 objects, you get `S_FALSE`.